# collective nouns subject verb agreement

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which of the following is correct?

The committee debates these questions carefully.

or

The committee debate these questions carefully.

I am confused on when to use plural form of the verb with collective nouns. Here each member of the committee is participating in the debate. Should we use plural verb (debate) in this case?

Comment: The answer is below and I see you have not reacted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Verb agreement with collective nouns**

> In British English, collective nouns, (i.e. nouns referring to
> particular groups of people or things), (e.g. staff, government,
> class, team) can be followed by a singular or plural verb depending on
> whether the group is thought of as one idea, or as many individuals,
> e.g.
>
> My team is winning. The other team are all sitting down. In American
> English, collective nouns are always followed by a singular verb, so
> an American would usually say:
>
> Which team is losing? whereas in British English both plural and
> singular forms of the verb are possible, as in:
>
> Which team is/are losing?

[collective nouns](https://www.onestopenglish.com/support-for-teaching-grammar/differences-in-american-and-british-english-grammar-article/152820.article#:%7E:text=In%20British%20English%2C%20collective%20nouns,My%20team%20is%20winning.)

Comment: I came across another example. "The staff argue with each other." Do we use 'the staff argues with each other' in American English? 
In the example that I have given in the question, the company members are debating among themselves. Should we use debate or debates?

Comment: @lokeshLP I have given you the answer.

Comment: One way we Americans might express that thought, @lokeshLP, is *The staff **members** argue with each other*. Similarly, *They **debate** [not \***debates**] among themselves*.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum The whole point is that AmE would use  "the staff debates" and BrE uses "the staff debate or debates". My answer could not be clearer.

Comment: @Lambie, “**the** whole point is”? OP did ask about collective nouns. But in the most recent comment, lokesh LP—to whom my comment is plainly addressed—mentions “the company members.” And I responded to that comment by providing one of the ways that Americans might convey the point. That I should have followed lokesh LP in shifting gears to discuss a form that plainly is not collective was hardly something to get cross about.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I'm not cross but I did answer the question. These askers ask a question, you answer it and then they ask the same question again. I have never understood that.

Comment: @Lambie, okay, I see. I guess that to the asker, the follow-on question isn’t “the same.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum, thanks for your answer and the comments here. I am sorry for not putting the follow-on question clearly. I am not a native English speaker. Before I ask a question here, I try to find an answer myself on the internet. You can refer to collective nouns section of this.  https://www.scribbr.com/verbs/subject-verb-agreement/ . Here they have given the differences usage of verbs with collective nouns in AmE and BrE. Here they have given the example 'The staff argue with each other.' in both AmE and BrE.

Comment: As per your answer @Lambie, Americans always use singular verb. Then I got a doubt. In the example 'The staff argue with each other', there is 'each other' at the end of the sentence, and thus may be we need to use singular verb even in AmE. Or may be it is just that the way they had presented AmE in this website is not proper. I am not sure. In this way the follow-on question is not the same. I have to explain this concept to some children and if I am not clear about it, I can't explain them.

Comment: @lokeshLP The staff [members] argue with each other. That's the ellipsis. [later I looked at that site you posted and it says]: **A plural verb makes more sense here, as the emphasis is on the individual staff members. That refers to both AmE and BrE.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, Americans treat collective nouns as singular for the purposes of verb agreement. Thus we have

> How many times **has** Baltimore beaten the Yankees this season?

(where *Baltimore* is being used metonymically to refer to the Major League Baseball team whose hometown is Baltimore), even though substituting the team’s name would require a shift:

> How many times **have** the Orioles beaten the Yankees this season?

In a perhaps counterintuitive extension of this team-name-*are* pattern, even *Miami Heat*, which gives every appearance of a singular noun phrase, is—when serving as the name of the National Basketball Association’s franchise in Florida—a collective noun used with the **plural** form of verbs as in

> The Heat **are** in fifth place in the Eastern Conference.

This is corroborated by Google *n*-grams, which show a blossoming of *Miami Heat **were*** that starts around 1992—four years after the franchise was established—and no occurrences at all of *Miami Heat **was***.

And, as one more example of humans’ seeming allergy to linguistic consistency, when it comes to replacing them with pronouns, even franchise cities’ names are treated as plural. So we have (seemingly ungrammatical but entirely idiomatic) constructions like

> If Baltimore **beats** the Yankees tonight, **they**’ll assure **themselves** a berth in the playoffs.

Comment: I don't get how your answer is different from mine which states:  In American English, collective nouns are always followed by a singular verb, so an American would usually say: [etc.]

Comment: @Lambie, despite being all-American as measured by frequency of use here, *The Heat **are*** sounds to my ear like a very British way of putting it. *The Heat* is a collective noun that Americans do not follow by a singular verb. That’s one way my answer is different from yours; yours says, “always.”

Comment: My answer does not contain the actual names of teams: The Miami Heat is an American professional basketball team based in Miami. They play in the Southeast Division of the Eastern Conference in the National Basketball Association (NBA). The team joined the NBA in 1988 as an expansion team,[1] and won the NBA championship in 2006, 2012 and 2013. [Wikipedia].

Comment: And that’s yet another difference, @Lambie, between my answer and yours.

Comment: Your answer is all about teams, which limits it somewhat, which is a special case of this plural/singular usage.